How to layout with flutter
I have a new UI with 2 items.
If the text in the first item is too long, I need to wrap it to a new line like the screenshot.
I don't know how to do.
Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks for your suggestion.
[UI screenshot]
(https://i.sstatic.net/kE1PCMrb.png)
I tried with Wrap widget but not working.
Here is current code:
 Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Text("builder name"),
      widget()
    ]


Please add your code or an example of some code that shows what you have implemented. Have you searched any other similar questions? If so, please add links to those questions.

Bind the text width so it knows when to wrap to the next line. To do this, I would recommend wrapping the Text Widget in an Expanded. As mentioned in the answer by Kasun you should also set softWrap to true. This should solve it for you.
 Row(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
  Expanded(child:Text("builder name", softWrap: true)),
  widget()
]

